# Phonegap/Cordova Neat way to reference UI changes when Orientation changes?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am wondering if there are any Neat ways to reference UI changes when orientation changes in Phonegap App.

Or i would have to do like this below for every single element??

```
if ((window.orientation == 90)||(window.orientation == -90)) {
                      var active_page3 = $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "getActivePage" );
    var id3 =active_page3.page().attr('id');
    if (id3==='page') {
           document.getElementById("headerimage").style.width = "30%";           
    }
```

Comment: Do you know `media queries`?

Comment: Nope, never heard of that before. Can you give me a link or something so i can get some reference? I just googled it something like this? @media (min-width: 700px), handheld and (orientation: landscape) { ... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) are exactly made for your problem. They are there for developing responsive webdesigns and also for developing hybrid applications ;-).

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

So, this media query means, that the `background-color` will only be blue, if the `screen max-width` is 300px.

Before I'm going to dive to deep into this topic, I would recommend you, to read the detailed and informative information about media queries over here: [W3Schools - Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

More information about this can be found everywhere in the www - just google for media queries, it is such a big thing that you of course will find relevant information.

**Belonging to the comment from John, just some additional information**

I tested it with jQuery in an application I already build before. So I used this command:

```
console.log($(window).height(), $(document).height(), $(window).width(), $(document).width());
```

In **portrait mode** the result is:

- `$(window).height()`: **568**
- `$(document).height()`: **568**
- `$(window).width()`: **320**
- `$(document).width()`: **320**

In landscape mode the result is:

- `$(window).height()`: **320**
- `$(document).height()`: **320**
- `$(window).width()`: **568**
- `$(document).width()`: **568**

I hope, this is clear enough?! =)

Comment: Thanks!!! Yup, i just read about it. Then i can save some space for HTML code and just put them in the css.

Comment: Sorry just 1 quick question, when i set the Max-width (max-width: 300px) or (orientation: landscape) when i rotate it, would the css then treats the width as the length of the phone right? It will treat the width as the height when on landscape mode?